# How to Create a Spring bean that accesses files outside of my Project Folder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can FileReadingMessageSource in Spring be used to create a Spring bean which can access files like a config files?

I am trying to access this:

-my app

C:\folder1\eclipseapp.jar

-config file

C:\folder1\config.properties

Please teach me to create Spring bean to access my "config.properties" file located outside my project folder.

Thanks

Comment: You can use @ConfigurationProperties and specific path to properties file

Comment: @kidnan1991 thanks, can ConfigurationProperties access the file outiside my project folder?

Comment: I google and ConfigurationProperties is for SpringBoot, im using SpringMVC